# CSS3 stylish scroll bar not working in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

. . Pure Css3 scroll bar is not working in IE and Firefox Guys. .  Can anyone tweak, So that it can work with the above said browsers. Here is the codes and fiddle (please view it in Chrome, Firefox & IE)

Html

```
<div class="scrollbar" id="ex3">
<div class="content">Example 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scrollbar{
width:150px;
height:300px;
background-color:lightgray;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:40px;
overflow-y:scroll;
float:left;
}

.content{
height:450px;
} 


#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar{
width:16px;
background-color:#cccccc;
} 

#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background-color:#B03C3F;
border-radius:10px;
}


#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#BF4649;
border:1px solid #333333;
}


#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
background-color:#A6393D;
border:1px solid #333333;
} 


#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
border:1px gray solid;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px gray inset;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7uk6S/)

Comment: Your css code is specific to WEBKIT ( Chrome, Safari ) -> `#ex3::-webkit-scrollbar`

Comment: If you need a cross browser solution you have to do it with javascript and custom elements. Something like: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: Actually i tried -moz- but it din work out. . Thats why i have posted this question

Comment: @Endless: So no chances of pure css3 to work in firefox??

Comment: use jScrollPane or similar JS plugin for cross browser solution. there is no reliable crossbrowser pure CSS implementation

Answer (score 1):

Just by using CSS3, it is definitely not yet compatible to all browsers especially IE. It is just same effect with the border-radius, etc.

Also, just by using `::-webkit-scrollbar`, obviously it only works for webkit browsers such as google chrome, safari..

I suggest you use a JS Plugin with that. jScrollPane is recommended! http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html